# how to Cross Referencing in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I come from DotNet and TSQL... so i still got some "problems" thinking in a NoSql way.

Basically I have 3 Tables / Classes and they need to know from each other (Cross-Referenced).
**Is the best way to do this with a relationtable (Class 1 ID - Class 2 ID etc)?**

Hope you can help with your experience!
Thanks

ps.

its build up like this:

Class 3 depends on Class 2 and that depends on Class 1

But from every "level" you should be able to figure out the connected Classes.
Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you want `reference` of document of one `collection` in another `collection` i.e .cross-referencing.

Mongoose provides a feature to use references of one document in another collection, **Mongoose Populate**. You can use this to do cross-referencing of one class with other and vice-versa.

From **Mongoose-Populate** documentation:

> **There are no joins in MongoDB but sometimes we still want references to documents in other collections. This is where population comes in.**
>
> **Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified
> paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s). We
> may populate a single document, multiple documents, plain object,
> multiple plain objects, or all objects returned from a query.**

for more information, please refer to [mongoose populate documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

I hope this is what you were looking for and it should help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I think i could make it work like that. Appreciate your effort!